# Remove duplicate nested objects in array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have an array which looks like below

```
var nestedArray = [
  { id: 1, filter: { type: "nestedArray", name: "5" } },
  { id: 2, filter: { type: "nestedArray1", name: "6" } },
  { id: 3, filter: { type: "nestedArray", name: "5" } }
];
```

Now here I have a duplicate object, I just want to identify the duplicates using a **Lodash** method. Any help is appreciated.

Have already tried **map**, filter options but need something in **Lodash** method.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  reject with a Property.

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "filter": {
      "type": "nestedArray",
      "name": "5"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "filter": {
      "type": "nestedArray1",
      "name": "6"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "filter": {
      "type": "nestedArray",
      "name": "5"
    }
  }
];

var result = _.reject(myArray, ['filter.name', '5']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This would work if the OP can use the id field as a unique identifier for the object.

Answer (score 1):

So u want to reject duplicate ones by value in filter key?

```
_.uniqWith(nestedArray, (x, y) => _.isEqual(x.filter, y.filter), myArray)
```

If you have the flexibility to use Ramda instead, it could be more concise like because of every functions are auto-curried

```
const rejectDuplicateFilter = R.uniqWith(R.eqProps('filter'));
rejectDuplicateFilter(myArray)
```